# SAS to LaTeX: Environment longtable undefined

Tags: environments, longtable

My general problem is that, after oh so many hours, I cannot find a way to bring SAS output into LaTeX.

I have one way where SAS spits out a table using the sas package, where it gives you tables in longtable.

Since I dont want my whole document to be formatted with the SAS package, I just copy and pasted the longtable.

Even after installing longtable (I think), I still get errors.

Any advise regarding either this problem, or just a better way to put SAS into LaTex, would be oh so appreciated.

Thanks so much.

Comment: This isn't enough information for anyone to help you. Edit your question to include the following: a document in `{article}` class that loads only the `longtable` package, and contains a sample table that you pasted from the other package. (Also, you shouldn't have had to install the `longtable` package, since it is part of any basic TeX distribution.)

Comment: My guess is that the table output is more dependent on the `sas` package than you think, and this is the source of the errors, but since I (and probably most other users of the site) don't have SAS to test anything with you'll need to do quite a bit to help us help you.

Comment: ok. thanks for your help. good lord am I struggling to understand how this works. thanks though. ill keep lookin.

Comment: If you can construct the minimal example as I describe, that should go a long way to helping to figure out the problem.

Comment: Just in case: You need to have `\usepackage{longtable}` somewhere in your `.tex` file if you want to `use` the `package` called `longtable`.

Comment: I've read countless threads, and I still just cannot figure out how to consistently install a package using Miktex. I use TexMaker to compile. I created a folder (C:\Users\Shaft\texmf\tex) to put the .sty files into after running the .ins, and I told Miktex that this was a root. The styles never appear in my Miktex list, and they never work in Texmaker. :( :(

Comment: Use the MikTeX package manager to install most things. There's very few packages that you should need to install in your local texmf folder as a general rule, and certainly not common packages like `longtable`. And if you tell MikTeX to install packages on the fly, it should install most missing things itself.

Comment: I must've goofed something in the early stages to not have longtable then. In any case, I think I got it: I needed C:\Users\Shaft\texmf\tex\latex, not just \tex.

Thanks for your patience. I know I didnt do as good a job as I shouldve posting this. Just...been working around the clock and I feel like my head is about to explode. I really do appreciate it.

Quick question though: if I dont have a package in MikTex, I assume I need to go to CNAT and get it that way, right? And when I install it, how come it doesn't show up in my MiKTeX thing? I assume at this point that it's not supposed to?

Answer (score 3):

SAS software has a suite which it calls
Output Delivery System (ODS)

In versions up to 8, the output file (myprogram.lst) was always a text file.
ODS supports named output to several popular vendor formats,
notably `*.pdf` and `*.rtf`, etc.,
and LaTeX.

This page describes the basics of creation of an output file
that is `*.tex`.

https://support.sas.com/rnd/base/ods/odsmarkup/latex.html

Based on what I see so far in this thread
the original poster does not have `\usepackage{longtable}`

%this is cut&paste from support.sas page above.

```
\documentclass{article}

 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

 \usepackage{longtable}%<---<<< missing

 \usepackage{graphicx}

 \usepackage{times}

 \begin{document}

 %... SAS output here ...

 %\input{my-output-from-sas-longtable} %.tex file

 %\input{my-output-from-sas-longtable-1} %.tex file

 %\input{my-output-from-sas-longtable-2} %.tex file

 \end{document}
```

notes:

`*`usepackage{sas}
sas.sty`is not in the TeXlive.2015 installation;
ODS creates the file`sas.sty`in the folder where the`*.sas` program was run;
it is 1,000+ lines and begins with a dozen

```
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}

...    \RequirePackage{longtable}
```

- `sas.sty` defines an environment `sastable`
  which is a relatively simple container for `longtable`
- the original poster stated he was using the plain output
  from `SAS.ODS` which write to separate `*.tex` 
  files which contain `longtable`

It seems to me that

`\usepackage{longtable}`

is what is missing.

Ron Fehd  {SAS} peer

{this Q fwd to me by bb}

Answer (score 0):

The StatRep package may help. It leverages the latex ODS destination to present your SAS output. Its main purpose is to provide environments to display SAS code that is then used to create a SAS program. More info here:
[StatRep Package info from SAS.](https://support.sas.com/rnd/app/papers/statrep.html)